# Java 1.8.0 enable TLS1.2 in JDBC connection

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have an SQL Server 2014 updated to the latest fixpack (**12.0.5207**). In the environment, the only protocol enabled is TLS1.2 (the registry keys has been set for the purpose). I can connect to the SQL server using the SA account both locally and remotely using Management Studio.

However when I try establishing a connection to the SQL server using java code and the JDBC driver **sqljdbc42.jar** the following exception is thrown:

> The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by
>   using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did
>   not return a response. The connection has been closed.

The java code is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println( e.toString() ); 
    }

    String connectionUrl =  "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +  
                            "databaseName=TRCDB;user=sa;password=**********;";  
    try 
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        System.out.println( e.toString() ); 
    } 
}
```

When the JVM is launched the following option are passed:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2" -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2"
```

So although only TLSv1.2 is enabled the "Client Hello" is done using TLSv1:

```
jdk.tls.client.protocols is defined as TLSv1.2 SSLv3 protocol was requested but was not enabled 
SUPPORTED: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] 
SERVER_DEFAULT: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] 
CLIENT_DEFAULT: [TLSv1.2] 
...
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
...
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake
...
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
```

Is it the **TLS** version the root cause of the problem?
How can I force **TLSv1.2**?

Comment: You could try adding `;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2` to your connection URL and see if that helps (ref: [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/pull/422)).

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: What version of the driver are you using? It looks like you'd need to be using version [6.3.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/tag/v6.3.2) or later in order to take advantage of the connection parameter I mentioned above.

Comment: I was using the JDBC 6.0. I switched to the newer version 6.3.2 and added the new property to the connection URL and it worked. Having said that the 6.3.2 it's a preview version and I won't use it in a production environment. Furthermore I would avoid changing the code (connection URL) and rebuild it since the code is part of a big project. I'm wondering why the "Client Hello" is sent using TLSv1 instead of the specified TLSv1.2.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Java 8 should use TLS1.2 by default: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/jdk-8-will-use-tls-12-as-default so the `sslProtocol` shouldn't be needed.

Comment: This is not a JRE related issue. Whatever version you are using the Microsoft JDBC driver will always assume that TLS v1.1 is enabled unless you specify the propery in the connection URL as answered by Gord.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Older versions of Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server apparently assume that TLS v1.1 will be available on the server. That is, they were not coded to handle the case where the server explicitly rejects (or ignores) TLS v1.1 traffic.

Starting with JDBC driver [version 6.3.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/tag/v6.3.2) we can add `;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2` to our connection URLs to specify the TLS version to use.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting this error with version 9.2.1.jre8. I just downgraded to 6.4.0.jre8 and that works though.

Comment: Using the enabledTLSProtocols connection URL parameters works for me, for example: `jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db>?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2`

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the driver fixed this issue for me.  Version downloaded from here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
and used in JBoss 7.2 server.  With this version I did not need to add anything to my connection URL.  I had to modify my module.xml for the new file name but did not need to alter the dependencies section.
I was getting the same response and this resolved it.  I did not add any -D JVM options like the OP mentions.

*** ClientHello, TLSv1
...
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake
...
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2

Comment: I still reproduce the problem with a JRE 1.8.0 and a JDBC driver 8.2.2.0 (mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar). Try the code above and you will end up with an error unless you specify ;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2 in the connection URL. Note that TLS1 and TLS1.1 are disabled on the MSSQL and HTTP server operating systems. More precisely the entries in  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL` are set for this purpose.