# Display ssl Protocol for JDBC connection

Tags: java

When I add the sslProtocol=TLSv1.2 to the connectionURL, How do I display the protocol that it is using to my screen when the getConnection take place to verify that TLSv1.2 is being use?

reference: [Java 1.8.0 enable TLS1.2 in JDBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464863/java-1-8-0-enable-tls1-2-in-jdbc-connection#51564973)

Answer (score 0):

I would look to enable logging output on the SQL Server driver, to see if it tells you about the particulars of the connections it sets up. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/tracing-driver-operation?view=sql-server-2017