# TLSv1.2 from Java to SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, tls1.2

SQL Server 2017.
Java 8 (u251).
sqljdbc42.jar.

I have disabled SSL versions below TLS 1.2 via [this](https://www.vircom.com/blog/running-sql-ssl-3-0-tls-1-0-disabled-without-losing-shirt/). I have enabled TLSv1.2 via [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server). I have installed a certificate via [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

The code used to create and use the connection is:

```
Connection connection = null;
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dbServerIp + ":" + dbServerPort + ";databaseName=" + dbName + ";sslProtocol=TLSv1.2;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUserName, dbPassword);
```

But it keeps failing. In java, I'm getting the stack trace with a message of

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".

Whereas a Wireshark trace shows one `TDS7 pre-login message`, followed by a `TDS7 Response` followed by a `TDS7 pre-login message TLS Exchange`, then a bunch of FIN and ACK.

None of these messages are very helpful. When I use SQL Server Management Studio with the encrypted option, it works fine. I need to figure out why my Java code is failing, but I've gotten nowhere with it all day.

**EDIT**: I updated to mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar and that didn't help either. On a whim, I tried just seeing if another application that uses Hibernate could still connect now that the server is forcing TLS 1.2, and without changing anything at all in the application or Hibernate's configuration.....and it just works. I see lots of traffic in Wireshark with `TLS Exchange`s and so forth. I must be missing something really elementary on this particular way of manually connecting through Java (this is a different application than the one using Hibernate).

Comment: Are you really using the v4.2 driver? The sslProtocol keyword was only added in [version 6.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver#64) of the Microsoft JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes, but I've tried it without that in the connection string because I haven't seen it mentioned as much, and it didn't make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464863/java-1-8-0-enable-tls1-2-in-jdbc-connection). Perhaps you could run your program with the following property: `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and paste the debug log into this question.